# If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then show this limit is $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Show the following limit is true:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{|(f(x+h) - f(x))(g(x+h) - g(x))|}{\|h\|} = 0.
\end{align*}

I believe the approach is to use the fact that $f$ and $g$ are continuous to show that $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} f(x+h) - f(x) = 0$, and analogously for $g$, but I'm confused by the denominator. Is it possible to invoke continuity without doing more manipulations of the quotient?

Note that this limit is part of the proof for the multivariable product rule.

Comment: Hint:$$\frac{|(f(x + h) - f(x))(g(x + h) - g(x))|}{\|h\|} = \|h\|\left|\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{\|h\|}\right|\left|\frac{g(x + h) - g(x)}{\|h\|}\right|.$$

Comment: You should use differentiability and the fact that a limit of product is a product of limits (when both exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $g$ is differentiable, so you know that
$$
\frac{|g(x+h)-g(x)|}{\|h\|}=\frac{|\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x)h_i+o(\|h\|)|}{\|h\|}\le \left|\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x) \right| + \varepsilon(h)
$$
where $\varepsilon(h)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$. So the second factor in your limit is bounded while the first, as you indicated, approaches zero. Therefore the limit is zero.

Comment: Apparently to many users the difference between $||h||$ and $\|h\|$ is not conspicuous. But look at $||h|| ||k||,$ coded as `||h|| ||k||`, versus $\|h\|\|k\|,$ coded as `\|h\|\|k\|`. $$ \begin{align} & {} \\ & ||h|| ||k|| \\ {} \\ & \|h\|\|k\| \end{align} $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are right. I was just being lazy.